# sql query to select record having same id but different value in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this -

[image]

Now look at the last two records with articleid=54

I want to select this record only once like - i want to select all records which have same articleid for (fieldsid=1 and value=1) and also for (fieldsid=2 and value=1)

The `articleid` must be same but it would check for the desired value in two different records.

Please somebody help me.

I am trying to do it like this -

```
select n1.id, n1.fieldsid, n1.value 
from `tablename` n1 
where (n1.fieldsid='1' and n1.value='1') 
and n1.id = (select n2.id 
             from `tablename` n2 
             where (n1.fieldsid='2' and n2.value='2') 
             and n1.id=n2.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT youtable.*
FROM yourtable
WHERE articleid IN (SELECT articleid
                    FROM yourtable
                    WHERE (fieldsid, value) IN ((1,1),(2,1))
                    GROUP BY articleid
                    HAVING COUNT(*)=2)
```

edit: if you only need the first record:

```
SELECT youtable.*
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(id)
             FROM yourtable
             WHERE (fieldsid, value) IN ((1,1),(2,1))
             GROUP BY articleid
             HAVING COUNT(*)=2)
```

Comment: it's quite correct fthiella, and thanks for this, but what if i want only a single record or only articleid a single time. Can you make it to print only one record per articleid, (say first record).

Comment: your earlier answer was quite correct, but this one is giving wrong results. by the way i made it through.

Comment: But can you explain what does `HAVING COUNT(*)=2` is meant by here..?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response fthiella. with your help i sorted it out like this -

```
SELECT joom_fieldsattach_values.*
FROM joom_fieldsattach_values
WHERE `articleid` IN (SELECT `articleid`
                FROM joom_fieldsattach_values
                WHERE (`fieldsid`, `value`) IN ((1,1),(2,1))
                GROUP BY `articleid`
                HAVING COUNT(*)=2)
                GROUP BY `articleid`
```