# SQL query condition for fetching user's answers with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named user_answers. This is the schema for the table.

[image]

Now, I want to create a query that can accomodate different condition.

For example:

*Select all users who answered 0 on question 1405 **OR** 3 on question 1628.*

It can also be filtered like

*Select all users who answered 0 on question 1405 **AND** 3 on question 1628.*

I have tried to search for similar queries in stackoverflow and found this [sql query to select record having same id but different value in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497348/sql-query-to-select-record-having-same-id-but-different-value-in-two-columns). I tried to implement it but it can't accommodate the OR conditions it can only cater AND.

I also tried to use the query below which I think might work but does not return any results.

```
select * from user_answers
    where 
    (user_id = user_id AND question_id= 1627 AND answer = 5) 
    AND (user_id = user_id AND question_id= 1626 AND answer = 0) ;
```

Is there anything wrong with the query above? Or are there any approach I can try?

PS: It is not only limited to one condition. It can be a combination of conditions like. (Q1 : A1) AND (Q2 : A2) OR (Q3 : A3) and so on ......

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Can you share the expected output.

Comment: and please provide the sample data as text

Comment: try something like this select * from user_answers
where user_id = user_id AND 
 question_id in (1627, 1626) AND 
    answer in (0,5) ;

Comment: What is the reason for doing `user_id = user_id`?

Comment: this query is wrong as question_id= 1627 AND answer = 5 AND question_id= 1626 AND answer = 0

Comment: I should have one or 2 result. user_id: 4348 since that user have answered both in the condition.

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yes, I tried that but that only supports queries for AND condition. There may be instances that either one is acceptable

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using `GROUP BY`.

Case `OR`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_answers
WHERE condition1 OR condition2
GROUP BY user_id
```

Case `AND`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_answers
WHERE condition1 OR condition2
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks @mm759. I tried the query for OR and I think it is working just fine. But how is it gonna be if both are included in the query? Like (question = 123 and answer = 0 ) OR (question = 124 AND answer = 2) AND (question = 122 AND answer = 0). Sorry I haven't mentioned in my question that the query can get a little complicated by adding more conditions.

Comment: `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR SUM(CASE WHEN condition2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND SUM(CASE WHEN condition3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

select * from user_answers where question_id=1405 and answer=0 or question_id=1405 and answer=0 groupby user_id